# i got this #1064 when i try to insert tin mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

i have an error when i try to input data to database
the details :

insert.php
and the code is :

```html
       <div align ="center" dir="rtl">
  <form dir="rtl"  method="GET" action="update.php">
    <div dir="rtl"class="row">
      <div>
        <label for="fname">  מספר מגמה &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </label>
    
        <input type="text" id="fname" readonly name="magma_no" value="<?=($row0['magma_no'] +1)?>">
      </div>
    </div>
 <br>
     <div dir="rtl"class="row">
      <div>
        <label for="fname">  שם מגמה &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </label>
    
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="mgma_name" placeholder="מספר כאן">
      </div>
    </div>
 <br>
 
     <div dir="rtl"class="row">
      <div>
        <label for="fname">  הסבר על מגמה  &nbsp &nbsp </label>
    
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="mgma_details" placeholder="מספר כאן">
      </div>
    </div>
 <br>
 <div  id="buttons" class="row">
      <input style="font-family:David" type="submit" class="btn blue"  value="הוספה למאגר" name="insert">
       </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and update.php

```
<?php
include "../include/config.php";
if(isset($_GET['insert'])){
    $query      ="SELECT count(*) as 'counter' FROM magma where         
magma_no='".$_GET['magma_no']."'";
$res  = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$rowing     = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
if( $rowing['counter'] == 0)
{
$insert="insert into magma (magma_no,mgma_name,mgma_details) VALUES ('".$_GET['magma_no']."','".$_GET['mgma_name']."','".$_GET['mgma_details']."')";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$insert);
if($query==1)
{
    ?>
           <script>alert('הוספה בהצלחה')</script>     
            <meta content="0;../magma.php?succeed" http-equiv="refresh">


    <?php


}else {
    ?>
                <script>alert('ERROR CODE="<?=mysqli_errno($con)?>"') 
</script>
<?php 
echo "<h1 align='center'>".mysqli_error($con)."</h1>";
?>

            <meta content="5;../magma.php?error" http-equiv="refresh">


    <?php

}
}else
{
?>
<script>alert('ERROR CODE=403')</script>
                                    <script>alert('ERROR MODE= מספר משתמש כבר קיים במערכת')</script>

            <meta content="0;insert.php?error" http-equiv="refresh">


<?php
}

}
?>
```

when i click submit
i got this error

> > You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1')' at line 1

can anyone help me to pass this error ?
i tried many ways

**update 1**

```
var_dump($_GET['magma_no'],$_GET['mgma_name'],$_GET['mgma_details']);
```

> > string(3) "103" string(23) "הנדסת חשמל ב'" string(1) "1"

Comment: Can you var_dump these variables `$_GET['magma_no']`, `$_GET['mgma_name']`, `$_GET['mgma_details']`and update your post. Will definetly  help.

Comment: Never ever use unescaped user data directly in your database queries. You should use parameterized prepared statements instead ir you will be wide open for SQL injection attacks...

Comment: @saibbyweb i updated

Comment: @marmsaeed try this for `$insert` and see if it works `$insert='INSERT INTO magma (magma_no,mgma_name,mgma_details) VALUES ("'. $_GET['magma_no'] . '","' . $_GET['mgma_name'] . '","' . $_GET['mgma_details'] . '")';`

Comment: @saibbyweb done and work !! what was the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_GET['mgma_name']` already has a single quote `'`, you were trying to use a single quote within single quotes. You need to wrap your `$_GET` variables within double quotes like this:

```
$insert='INSERT INTO magma 
(magma_no,mgma_name,mgma_details) 
VALUES 
("'. $_GET['magma_no'] . '","' . $_GET['mgma_name'] . '","' . $_GET['mgma_details'] . '")';
```

EDIT:

As suggested by [Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson), you should definitely use prepared statements. Here's an [fantastic article](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage) covering basic mysql usage including prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you very much bro , and you are absolutely right

Comment: Just a warning. This solution is _very_ insecure and will leave you wide open to SQL injection attacks. If you use parameterized prepared statements, not only would the quoting issue be a non-issue, your code would also be much more secure. You should _never_ trust user data.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Updated!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are right , and i shoud use the function mysqli_real_escape to escape the data from forms

Comment: @marmsaeed - You should use Prepared Statements instead. Using that will send the query with placeholders and the actual data separately, making SQL injections/escaping a non-issue. Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php